# How to detect if a web app is running in Electron

Tags: reactjs, web, electron, desktop-application

I'm trying to serve real react app on electron app. It doesn't mean I'm developing electron app with react. I've created a react app and injected it into electron app. (Like slack, it will serve as a web application and desktop application.) But I'm confused that send desktop notifications.

Now the main question is:
How can I get the application type. I mean, is user using my app on web or on desktop. How can I get this?

Thank you :)

Comment: There are many ways to do that, you can use [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) and you can set the value when you call [loadURL](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winloadurlurl-options)

Comment: Aaaah that makes sense!! Can you add an answer? I want to accept it. Thank you btw :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect an Electron instance via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725325/detect-an-electron-instance-via-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to detect whether you are running in a desktop environment or not.

You can check the [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) and you can set the `userAgent` value in Electron when you call [loadURL](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winloadurlurl-options).

Another way is declaring a global variable using a `preload` script.

```js
// main process
new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    preload: "preload.js",
  },
});

// preload.js 
// you don't need to use contextBridge if contextIsolation is false
// but it's true by default in Electron 12
const { contextBridge } = require("electron"); 
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("IN_DESKTOP_ENV", true);

// renderer process (your React world)
if (globalThis.IN_DESKTOP_ENV) {
  // do something...
}
```

[image]